# Declaring some constants associated with a protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I like to declare some constants associated to a protocol in Swift.  I know `Notification.Name` can declare some constant like the code below.  But I cannot declare any constants like the same way as `Notification.Name`.

I am wondering... is there any workaround? I prefer not to implement in its concrete type because this constant can be used in other concrete type too.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let helloNotification = Notification.Name("hello")
        // no comple error
}

protocol HelloProtocol: AnyObject {
}

extension HelloProtocol {
    static let hello1 = "Hello1"
        // error: Static stored properties not supported in protocol extensions
    static let hello2 = String("hello2")
        // error: Static stored properties not supported in protocol extensions
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, `Notification.Name` is not a protocol...

Comment: What's the question? What you're doing with Notification.name is legal because Notification.Name is not a protocol. What you're doing with a protocol is illegal. It's hard to see what the difficulty is.

Comment: I see.  I totally forgot about Notification.Name is not a protocol, right.  My intent of this question is that I like to provide some constant associated with a protocol.   Bringing Notification.Name misled my intent sorry.

Comment: Protocols aren't meant to be used like that. If you use `static var hello1: String { "Hello" }`, `hello1` would be available on all the types that conform to `HelloProtocol`, but you can't do `HelloProtocol.hello1`. Protocols are sets of requirements, not places where you put constants.

Comment: I disagree that protocols aren't *meant* to be used like that. It's been discussed many times on the forums, and the current situation is that it's just too hard to do because of the way protocols are implemented (and there have been changes to allow it somewhat to help SwiftUI). But I totally agree that protocols *can't* do this today. It's a reasonable thing to want, but it's not available. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0299-extend-generic-static-member-lookup.md#allow-declaring-static-members-directly-on-protocol-metatypes